# DCM4CHE 3.3.7 Send file error

Tags: server, dcm4che

I am attempting to send across a DICOM file to a DicomProxy, which is meant to convert the file and output to another server. However when executing the following command:

```
bin/storescu -c DICOMPROXY@XX.XXX.XXX.XX:XXXX ../example/XXXXXX.dcm
```

in the terminal, the following message appears.

```
Connected to DICOMPROXY in 35ms
org.dcm4che3.net.NoPresentationContextException: No Presentation Context for Abstract Syntax: 1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.1.2 - CT Image Storage negotiated
    at org.dcm4che3.net.Association.pcFor(Association.java:795)
    at org.dcm4che3.net.Association.cstore(Association.java:829)
    at org.dcm4che3.net.Association.cstore(Association.java:823)
    at org.dcm4che3.tool.storescu.StoreSCU.send(StoreSCU.java:483)
    at org.dcm4che3.tool.storescu.StoreSCU.sendFiles(StoreSCU.java:387)
    at org.dcm4che3.tool.storescu.StoreSCU.main(StoreSCU.java:296)
09:49:20,037 INFO  - STORESCU->DICOMPROXY(1) << A-RELEASE-RQ
09:49:20,037 DEBUG - STORESCU->DICOMPROXY(1): enter state: Sta7 - Awaiting A-RELEASE-RP PDU
09:49:20,038 INFO  - STORESCU->DICOMPROXY(1) >> A-RELEASE-RP
09:49:20,039 INFO  - STORESCU->DICOMPROXY(1): close Socket[addr=/XX.XXX.XXX.XX,port=XXXX,localport=50596]
09:49:20,039 DEBUG - STORESCU->DICOMPROXY(1): enter state: Sta1 - Idle
Sent 0 objects (=0MB) in 0.022s (=0MB/s)
```

Does anybody know the reason why the file will not send?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured the issue out, I was doing the syntax for storescu incorrectly. it should be like so:

`bin/storescu -c DICOMPROXY@XX.XXX.XXX.XX:XXXX -b AET:PORT ../example/XXXXXX.dcm`

Where -c represents the destination and -b represents the modality.